# New line for footnote without blank space

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes

Writing texts I found it visually more appealing to type footnotes in a new line, because it enhances the readability of the document. The problem is that it leads to a blank character in the output. Could there anything be done about this problem?

So what I write looks like this:

```
asdf asdf asdf asdf.
\footnote{bla bla bla}
asdf asdf asdf
```

Note: I am aware that the problem doesnt occur when I place a `%` following the last character (or punctuation) in the previous line. To me that doesnt seem elegant.

Answer (score 10):

Just add `\unskip` at the beginning of the definition of `\footnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\footnote}{\unskip}{}{}

\begin{document}
asdf asdf asdf asdf.
\footnote{bla bla bla}
asdf asdf asdf
\end{document}
```

But I don't think this is a good way to type one's documents. A good editor will highlight differently the argument of `\footnote`.

Answer (score 6):

Two solutions:

(1) Use the `sepfootnotes` package for the **greatest** readability:

```
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{a}
\begin{document}

\anotecontent{foo}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}

asdf asdf asdf asdf.\anote{foo}
asdf asdf asdf

\end{document}
```

(2) Or just put the command in the first line but the argument in the second.

```
asdf asdf asdf asdf.\footnote
{bla bla bla}
asdf asdf asdf
```

Comment: Thirs solution: end the line before `\footnote` with `%`.

Comment: #2 works for me -- very simple and no additional packages needed. Thanks!