# Best practice for source editing of footnotes

Tags: footnotes

If I write a footnote as follows:

```
abc\footnote{XYZ}
```

it doesn't leave a space after abc, which is ok. If I write as follows, with the hope of tidying up the source:

```
abc
\footnote{XYZ}
```

it leaves a space after abc.

Because footnotes are structurally separate from the text, it would be nice if I could keep them on their own lines in the source file, while preventing the space.

What is the best practice of source editing in this and similar cases?

Comment: Well you could use `abc%` and then latex doesn't notice that the `\footnote` is on a new line, so no unwanted space before the footnote. [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/106162).  Also see [New line for footnote without blank space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94563/106162) for other ways to deal with the footnote spacing *if* you watn to place `\footnote` on a new line.

Answer (score 4):

For short notes, you can do this:

```
This is body text.%
  \footnote{This is footnote.}
```

For longer notes, you can use the `semantic-markup` package, which provides a `Footnote` environment:

```
This is body text.%
  \begin{Footnote}
  This is a long footnote.
  See how many sentences there are.
  \end{Footnote}
```

In either case, you have to "escape" the end-of-line character by putting a `%` at the end of the line before the footnote.

Comment: Full disclosure: I am the package author.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you write in TEI XML you still have the same problem with space before a footnote: You have to write `<p>Body text<note>Footnote text</note></p>` if you don't want a space. Or you can do exactly the same as in LaTeX and escape the end-of-line by using half of a comment tag `<!--` at the end of one line and the other half before the note `--><note>` You can probably get around this with XSLT, just like you could try using `\unskip` with TeX footnotes.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient solution that works without additional packages is to use the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` commands instead of `\footnote`:

```
Lorem ipsum \footnotemark dolor sit amet.
\footnotetext{Here goes the text}
```